# selection expression to display the first 5 rows only in QGIS 3.8.3

Tags: qgis, query, select

I would like to display the first 5 rows only in QGIS 3.8.3 from the attribute table of a layer in ascending order.

I tried many selection expressions, but, none of them seems to work.

Is it possible to perform such querry in QGIS, if yes, plz provide me with querry proposition.

Comment: Is it a sort of specific query or you intended simply to select rows within the top5 list of values? Btw is a selection query or filter query?

Comment: Please provide some example queries which didn't work, thank you.

Comment: for ordering  it is solved.

Comment: however, here is an example for selectiong the top 5 rows that doesn't work , I used thecount function as follows:   count(population) <'6' , where population is a column of the attribute table, and plz note that the usage of quotations is mandatory, otherwise the expression is not recognized by the qgis querry analyzer. I tried  different expressions similar to the one mentioned above but none of them worked.